# connection to server on socket failed postgres ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, rvm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run postgres on ubuntu and it shows the following error

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

I have made research all through the internet yet to no avail. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: How did you install PostgreSQL?  How did you attempt to start it?  What does the log file say?  And what is rvm and what does it have to do with this?

Comment: I installed it using documentations from the postgres website. Although i've solved the error now. What i did was that i uninstalled it and reinstalled it using docs from microsoft wsl website